# Link taxonomy terms to view filtered on term?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I am trying to do something that is probably quite common but I'm not sure where to start. I have a view of content types with several taxonomy fields. There are exposed filters for users to filter the content. 
When on the node page for one of these nodes I would like the taxonomy terms to go to that view, already filtered on that taxonomy term. I am thinking maybe a GET request somehow.

Does anybody know how to accomplish this?
Let me know if this needs clarification.